# Retriving specific field of child collection using projection

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, projection

```
   class Post {
  @Id
  Long id;
  String title;
 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
                cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.MERGE,

                })
        @JoinTable(name = "post_tags",
                joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "post_id") },
                inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id") })

    Set<Tag> tags;
// constructor
// getters
// setters
}

class Tag{
   @Id
   Long id
   String name;
// getters, setter, constructor
}

interface PostProjection{
     Long getId();
     String getTitle();
 @Value("#{target.tags.size()}")
     int  getNumberOfTags();

}
```

In PostProjection I would like to retrive the name of each tags belong to this post. I am able to get the number of tags for a specific post but not the name of the tag. I don't want the tag id.I tried doing this:

```
 @Value("#{target.tags.name}")
         Set<String getTagsNanes();
```

But that doesn't work. 
How can retrieve the name of every tag belong enter to a specific post using projection? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is to avoid using [Open Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces.open) unless you really need that. Remember that, according with [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces.open), when using Open Projections, Spring will not optimize your query.

> Spring Data cannot apply query execution optimizations in this case,
>   because the SpEL expression could use any attribute of the aggregate
>   root.

The solution above ([Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)) will get a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of Tag names from your projection.

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toSet;

public interface PostProjection {
    String getTitle();

    Set<Tag> getTags();

    default Set<String> getTagsNames() {
        return getTags().stream().map(Tag::getName).collect(toSet());
    }

}
```